# NullPointerException with Sharing Intent in Android Nougat

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Currently, I'm trying to create a Sharing Intent to be called in the Android application itself when you click a "share" button to share an image. However, with the change to how Sharing Intents function in Android Nougat, I am getting a NullPointerException on this line:

```
Uri uImageFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DetailActivity.this, DetailActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), imageFile);
```

This was the error that I received:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:584)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:558)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
```

Here's the full code for my Share Intent method:

```
private void shareIntent() {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
    File imageFile = new File(data.get(pos).getUrl());
    Uri uImageFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DetailActivity.this, DetailActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), imageFile);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uImageFile);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share_to)));
}
```

`data.get(pos).getUrl()` returns the URL of a custom class I made that implements `Parcelable`, and when printing it out, it returns a directory like the following:
`"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/primitive/Primitive-79538313.jpg"`

Thank you for any help that you can provide!

Comment: Does your app has permission to access external storage?

Comment: Yes, I gave the program both these permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
private void shareIntent() {
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     shareIntent.setType("image/jepg");
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+data.get(pos).getUrl()));
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image"));
}
```

Add this code in your activity `onCreate()`

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```